# I'm using dp for my buttons ,graphics, and layouts. Buttons in the wrong place

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, button, android-xml

Is the Eclipse graphical layout editor consistent with actual phone realities? I only own a droid x and have nothing to test say a "2.7 in QVGA: setting with.
I have a button I want to show up in a specific place on the phone. I use the buttons properties to set a specific  layout height  and layout width and specific layout margin left and top using dp units , however when I change phone sizes in the emulator the buttons are the wrong size and wrong place on a lot of them. The buttons work and are laid out correctly on the screen for the "4in WVGA (Nexus S)" and they work great on my droid X. But when I change the emulator to "2.7in QVGA"  the button has moved way down the screen. Doesn't dp mean that the buttons will remain proportionate to the screen size? 
Ps I have placed appropriate DPI'd images into their respective Res Drawable folders ie: drawable-hdpi and drawable-ldpi , etc.
I thought maybe i could use weight, but I have never used that before and maybe I am just missing something stupid. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The size and position, relative to the topleft corner should be the same on each device. But, there are some devices which have a different resolution in height and width, which means that you will have more or less pixels in width/height on different devices, although they might share the same density. For example there are devices which have 800px in height, and some which have 854px, but they have both hdpi-density, so you will have the same margin to the topleft corner on both devices, but a different to the bottomright corner for example.